# adding ExtensionInstallSources in the registry does show up in the chrome://policy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I added following in the registry and after restarting chrome I can see that the policies are loaded in chrome://policy/

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallSources]
    "1"="http://hello.com/*"

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallSources]
"1"="http://hello.com/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallWhitelist]
 "1"="agnifkojepmocepodhnjonjmabopasdf"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallWhitelist]
 "1"="agnifkojepmocepodhnjonjmabopasdf"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallSources]
"1"="http://hello.com/*"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallWhitelist]
 "1"="agnifkojepmocepodhnjonjmabopasdf"
```

But this does not work on some workstations. They can not see the polices in  chrome://policy/ even after adding registries.

anything specific I need to check for?

Comment: Try [logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) the startup of Chrome on those machines.

Comment: log shows the following..

[3408:4312:0815/092613:VERBOSE1:policy_loader_win.cc(433)] Reading policy from the registry is disabled.

I looked at the code in win.cc file and found out that my machine need to be on the domain to be able to set the registries I mentioned above. This won't work for me as my organization does not require all the workstations to be on the domain.